# When to use ViewModel or Fragment newInstance function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So the question is simple: When is it best to use a ViewModel and getting data from that versus using the newInstance function on a fragment and passing the data through the creation.

I've tried googling it, but there doesn't seem to be much out there. Not anything I can easily seem to find.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModel` together with `LiveData` will store the values throughout the life cycle of the Fragment/Activity. It can also observe the underlying data so when the `ViewModel` changes your views will be automatically notified and updated. Read more about MVVM.